# Puppeteer Element Handle loses context when navigating

Tags: puppeteer

What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to get a screenshot of every element example in my storybooks project. The way I'm trying to do this is by clicking on the element and then taking the screenshot, clicking on the next one, screenshot etc.

Here is the attached code:

```
test('no visual regression for button', async () => {
  const selector = 'a[href*="?selectedKind=Buttons&selectedStory="]';
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080');
  let examples = await page.$$(selector);
  await examples.map( async(example) => {
    await example.click();
    const screen = await page.screenshot();
    expect(screen).toMatchImageSnapshot();
  });
  await browser.close();
});
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.

  at Session._onClosed (../../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:209:23)
  at Connection._onClose (../../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:116:15)
  at Connection.dispose (../../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:121:10)
  at Browser.close (../../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Browser.js:60:22)
  at Object.<anonymous>.test (__tests__/visual.spec.js:21:17)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

I believe it is because the element loses its context or something similar and I don't know what methods to use to get around this. Could you provide a deeper explanation or a possible solution? I don't find the API docs helpful at all.

Comment: it might happen because page crash, which version you use?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo I'm using the latest version

Comment: can you make a repo which contain minimal code to reproduce that behaviour? i mean the web page

Comment: I can't. I made some progress but got stuck on this: am I able to use page.screenshot() inside page.evaluate? I basically want to take a screenshot of every story inside react storybook.

Comment: i think it not possible, inside evaluate you are in browser context. Alternatively you can return promise, then add callback when the promise resolved. You screenshot via that callback.

Comment: i think you should update your question, so people are able to answer your question

Comment: I fixed it by setting the browser and page inside beforeAll().

Comment: Kindly answer your own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

ElementHandle.dispose() is called once page navigation occurs as garbage collection as stated here in the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle). So when you call `element.click()` it navigates and the rest of the elements no longer point to anything.